# Dynamically create a multilevel/nested TreeView with checkbox from Json file in WPF using C#

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml, treeview

I am working in WPF on creating a treeview from a JSON file. The structure of Json file (Template.json) is

```
{
  "Version": 1,
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Name": "Root",
      "Checked": true,
      "Children": [
        {
          "Name": "item1",
          "Checked": true,
          "Children": [
            {
              "Name": "item1 1",
              "Checked": true
            },           
            {
              "Name": "item1 2",
               "Checked": true
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "Name": "item2",
          "Checked": true
        },
        {
          "Name": "item3",
          "Checked": true
        },
        {
          "Name":"item4",
          "Checked":true,
          "Children":[
            {
                "Name":"item4 1",
                "Checked":true
            },
            {
                "Name":"item4 2",
                "Checked":true
            },
           ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

and my requirement is to create a treeview like below image

[image: Required TreeView]

For populating the data I have created below C# files

```
public class ChildModel
{
    private bool? Checked;
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public bool Checked { get; set; }
    public ChildModel Parent { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ChildModel> Children;
}

public class TemplateModel : ChildModel
{
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public List<ChildModel> Headers { get; set; }
}
```

and I am using the TemplateModel class in this ViewModel class

```
public class TemplateViewModel : TemplateModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

And finally I am binding the above viewmodel in xaml.cs file like below

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private TemplateViewModel TemplateVM;
    public TemplateViewModel TemplateVM 
    {
        get => TemplateVM;
        set
        {
            TemplateVM = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TemplateVM));
        }
    
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //path for template json file
        string pathTemplate = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + "\\jsonfiles";
        //json template file
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathTemplate, "Template.json");
        //Read the text from json file
        var jsonText = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        //map the jsonfile text data with class
        var template = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TemplateModel>(jsonText);
        
        foreach(var node in template.Headers)
        {
            node.Parent = template;
            foreach(var childNode in node.Children)
            {
                childNode.Parent = node;
                if(childNode.Children != null)
                {
                    foreach(var greatChildNode in childNode.Children)
                    {
                        greatChildNode.Parent = childNode;
                        if(greatChildNode.Children != null)
                        {
                            foreach(var great2ChildNode in greatChildNode.Children)
                            {
                                great2ChildNode.Parent = greatChildNode;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        TemplateVM = new TemplateViewModel()
        {
            Version = template.Version,
            Headers = template.Headers
        };
        this.pop.DataContext = this.TemplateVM;
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    private void Button_Click_AddNewTemplate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pop.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void Button_Click_ClosePopup(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pop.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

My MyWindow.xaml file looks like below

```
<Grid>
        <Button Content="Add new template" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="5" Click="Button_Click_AddNewTemplate" />
    <Popup x:Name="pop" Placement="Center" Width="300" Height="200" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade" >
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <StackPanel Background="AliceBlue">
                <!--ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxItemTemplate}" -->
            <Button Content="X" Click="Button_Click_ClosePopup" Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Red"  FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="20" Margin="2" />
            <TextBlock Text="Tree View" />
                <!--Headers-->
                <TreeView x:Name="tree" ItemsSource="{Binding Headers, Mode=OneTime}" Height="50" >
                    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        <!--Level1-->
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="2 0 0 0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                <!--Level 2-->
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeView>
            <Button Content="Save" Background="DarkBlue" Foreground="White" Margin="10" Height="30" />
        </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

But I'm unable to get the desired result. I'm only getting the root element and that's it.
What I'm doing wrong? I will be glad and very thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: If your tree is binding to Headers then your <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"> needs to bind to <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Headers}"> since Headers  is the name of the property that's really holding the children.